# TabControl implementation of ApplicationCommands.Delete

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am attempting to extend TabControl so that I can add and delete items, I have previously done this by adding a close command to my viewmodel that raises an event and a subscription in the parent viewmodel will remove the item from the collection.

I would like to make this approach more generic and am attempting to implement the ApplicationCommands.Delete command.

**ExtendedTabControl.cs**

```
public class ExtendedTabControl : TabControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CanUserDeleteTabsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CanUserDeleteTabs", typeof(bool), typeof(ExtendedTabControl), new PropertyMetadata(true, OnCanUserDeleteTabsChanged, OnCoerceCanUserDeleteTabs));

    public bool CanUserDeleteTabs
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(CanUserDeleteTabsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CanUserDeleteTabsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static RoutedUICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get { return ApplicationCommands.Delete; }
    }

    private IEditableCollectionView EditableItems
    {
        get { return (IEditableCollectionView)Items; }
    }

    private bool ItemIsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.SelectedItem != CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder)
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    }

    private static void OnCanExecuteDelete(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((WorkspacesTabControl)sender).OnCanExecuteDelete(e);
    }

    private static void OnCanUserDeleteTabsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The Delete command needs to have CanExecute run.
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }

    private static object OnCoerceCanUserDeleteTabs(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        return ((WorkspacesTabControl)d).OnCoerceCanUserAddOrDeleteTabs((bool)baseValue, false);
    }

    private static void OnExecutedDelete(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((WorkspacesTabControl)sender).OnExecutedDelete(e);
    }

    static ExtendedTabControl()
    {
        Type ownerType = typeof(ExtendedTabControl);

        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(ownerType, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ExtendedTabControl)));

        CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(ownerType, new CommandBinding(DeleteCommand, new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(OnExecutedDelete), new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler(OnCanExecuteDelete)));
    }

    protected virtual void OnCanExecuteDelete(CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // User is allowed to delete and there is a selection.
        e.CanExecute = CanUserDeleteTabs && ItemIsSelected; 
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    #endregion

    protected virtual void OnExecutedDelete(ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemIsSelected)
        {
            object currentItem = SelectedItem;
            int indexToSelect = Items.IndexOf(currentItem) - 1;

            if (currentItem != CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder)
                EditableItems.Remove(currentItem);

            // This should focus the row and bring it into view. 
            SetCurrentValue(SelectedItemProperty, Items[indexToSelect]);
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private bool OnCoerceCanUserAddOrDeleteTabs(bool baseValue, bool canUserAddTabsProperty)
    {
        // Only when the base value is true do we need to validate
        // that the user can actually add or delete rows. 
        if (baseValue)
        {
            if (!this.IsEnabled)
            {
                // Disabled TabControls cannot be modified. 
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((canUserAddTabsProperty && !this.EditableItems.CanAddNew) || (!canUserAddTabsProperty && !this.EditableItems.CanRemove))
                {
                    // The collection view does not allow the add or delete action.
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return baseValue;
    }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

```
<!-- This template explains how to render a tab item with a close button. -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="CloseableTabItemHeader">
    <DockPanel MinWidth="120">
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete" Content="X" Cursor="Hand" Focusable="False" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold" Height="16" Width="16" />
        <TextBlock Padding="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type local:ExtendedTabControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabControl}}" TargetType="{x:Type local:ExtendedTabControl}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CloseableTabItemHeader}" />
</Style>
```

This nearly works, I can choose an item and remove it by either hitting my close button or using the delete key. However if I hit the close button of an item that isn't selected, it still removes the selected item. The reason for this behavior is obvious, but I'm not sure how to access the correct object for removal? I also need to assign the indexToSelect found in OnExecutedDelete in a better fashion though I'm comfortable I'll find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecutedRoutedEventArgs` has property `Parameter`. Try to set `DataContext` of `TabItem` as `CommandParameter`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CloseableTabItemHeader">
<DockPanel MinWidth="120">
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Content="X" Cursor="Hand" Focusable="False" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold" Height="16" Width="16" />
    <TextBlock Padding="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</DockPanel>
```

Then you can access `DataContext` in `OnExecutedDelete`:

```
protected virtual void OnExecutedDelete(ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ItemIsSelected)
    {
        object currentItem = e.Parameter ?? SelectedItem;
        int indexToSelect = Items.IndexOf(currentItem) - 1;

        ...
    }

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: The solution as stated has the side effect of breaking the "del" key functionality, perhaps you could make a minor edit(e.Parameter ?? SelectedItem).

Answer (score 0):

I've just done something very similar in http://dragablz.net

Two check-ins for managing add and remove of tabs:

https://github.com/ButchersBoy/Dragablz/commit/47bbc302f5ffeaa8c234269ab4ff11bc80f7fa10
https://github.com/ButchersBoy/Dragablz/commit/c1dce0435683db83f163a77ccb9a19b3218b3ca7